# docker-compose not deploying to remote machine

Tags: linux, docker, ubuntu, docker-compose, docker-machine

I'm trying to deploy a docker project to a remote VPS, I use docker-machine to create a remote instance, but despite setting (I think) local docker environment variables, docker-compose does not build to the remote machine.

- I've created a remote VPS via `docker-machine create`.
- I then run `eval $(docker-machine env test)`
- `docker-machine active` confirms I'm 'on' the remote machine, as does my - now modified - command prompt.
- when I run both `docker-compose build` & `docker-compose up` I get the following error:
  'ERROR: SSL error: [SSL: TLSV1_ALERT_PROTOCOL_VERSION] tlsv1 alert protocol version (_ssl.c:590)' (I've searched, but haven't found how to resolve this.)
- instead I prepend sudo, making the commands `sudo docker-compose build` & `sudo docker-compose up`
- running them both produces no errors, the problem is my containers are spun up locally (`docker ps` agrees), and not remotely at the ip garnered from `docker-machine ip test`

I am using ubuntu 16 locally.

Docker version 18.06.1-ce, build e68fc7a

docker-compose version 1.8.0, build unknown

docker-machine version 0.16.0, build 702c267f

Comment: Before running docker-compose, what does `docker info` output?

Comment: You should also consider upgrading docker-compose, 1.8 is quite old. Current release is over 1.23.

Comment: @BMitch the output of `docker info` sounds like the droplet on digital ocean I created, based on memory provider label. I can post the exact output if it helps.

Comment: @BMitch I update docker-compose to 1.23.2. Now I don't get ssl errors, but otherwise things are the same.

Comment: apologies, updating docker-compose has indeed fixed things ! Thanks so much

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. You should use another site on the [Stack Exchange network](https://stackexchange.com/sites) for this question.

Comment: @jww docker is a well established technology for developers to run & test their code, although the question talks about running the code on a remote machine I see it as developer oriented as all this occurred in my developing/testing workflow. What network site would you better recommend? I think serverfault isn't such an obvious fit since docker abstracts servers away, and all of this question pertains to a normal development environment. What do you think?

Answer (score 2):

Following the suggestion from @BMitch to update docker-compose the problem is resolved. I am now running docker-compose 1.23.2, build 1110ad01 which builds and deploys as expected.

Also, the SSL errors are gone.